# Why the destructor is not being called when we create object with "NEW" keyword?

Tags: c++

I have created a class with one constructor and destructor. In main function, I have created a pointer and initialize to my class with "new" keyword.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class RAVI 
{ 
    public: 
    RAVI() 
    { 
        cout<<"in constructor"<<endl; 
    } 
    ~RAVI() 
    { 
        cout<<"in Distructor"<<endl;
    } 
};

int main()
{ 
    RAVI *p; 
    try{ 
        p= new RAVI(); 
        cout<<"throughng object"<<endl; 
        throw 6;
    } 
    catch(...)
    { 
        cout<<"Caught exception"<<endl; 
    } 
    cout<<"end of try-catch block"<<endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

This give output:

```
in constructor 
throughng object 
Caught exception 
end of try-catch block
```

Usually destructor should call before throwing the exception. But in the below case why it is not happening??

Please clarify my doubt?

Comment: post code in question.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it's impossible to format. Instead *edit your question*.

Comment: And where do you `delete` your object? If you don't `delete` it then then why should the destructor be called? You never destroy the object. Remember that this is C++ and not Java/C#, objects are not garbage collected.

Comment: What output do you see? (and how does that differ to what you were expecting?)

Comment: if you do `RAVI p();` instead inside the try block, it will always destruct

Comment: @sp2danny 'if you do `RAVI p();` ... This is a function declaration! Should be `RAVI p;`

Comment: This is the output.... in constructor
throughng object
Caught exception
end of try-catch block

Comment: @RowlandShaw: It should call destructor before it going to caught the exception. And it is working fine when I created object directly with out pointers.

Comment: ouch! "the most vexing parse"

Comment: When you exit from scope, then the destructor function will work. And you can't call it. it works as automatically. destructor will work after finishing program. For seeing the result, you can write an simple examlple, using another class not the main class...!

Answer (score 4):

> Usually destructor should call before throwing the exception

**WRONG**. The object is allocated in heap, and will reside in memory until program terminates. If you used stack to create the object *inside* the `try` block, then it would get destroyed when that block ends, but still *after* the `throw` statement.

```
 try{ 
  RAVI p;
  cout<<"throughng object"<<endl; throw 6; } 
 catch(...) 
{ 
  cout<<"Caught exception"<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
in constructor
throughng object
in Distructor
Caught exception
end of try-catch block
```

I guess you assumed "Usually destructor should call before throwing the exception " from the knowledge that if an exception is thrown, stack will unwind and destroy all the objects *created in that scope* . But this is true for objects (including pointers, but not the *pointed objects*) that **reside in stack**, not in heap. That's the motivation of using *smart pointer* instead of raw pointer, so that when stack unwinds, the heap objects will be also destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of all local variables leaving scope will be
called.  In your case, there are no local variables leaving
scope, so no destructors will be called.  If `RAVI* p;` were in
the try block, its destructor would be called.  But the
destructor of a pointer is a no-op, so you can't tell whether it
was called or not.

When you create an object with `new`, you're telling the
compiler that you want to manage its lifetime.  The only time
its destructor will be called is when you tell the compiler to
do so, with `delete`.

Comment: Smart answer. So in case if we use pointers to create object there will be waste of memory. Is my understanding correct?? Also, if we need to throw the exception manually with the help of throw then what is the real use of try-block?? We can directly use if conditions to ignore abnormal run time errors. Isn't it?

Comment: @user3664676 I don't understand.  You use pointers when you need pointers; they don't necessarily imply dynamic allocation.  And you use dynamic allocation when you want the object to continue to exist even after you leave scope.  And the use of a try block is to catch an exception thrown on a lower level.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get you. We can write one if condition instead of this try-catch, right? For example, in case of devide by zero exception, we can write one if condtion i.e. if denominator is equal to zero print some statement. Is this make any sense?

Comment: @user3664676 If the error is to be handled immediately at the location it occurs, then it should be handled there, without any exception.  There are cases, however, where the error can only be handled twenty or thirty functions up the call stack.  Having to check the return code at each level would be a pain.  And what if the error occurs in a constructor?  There is no return code.